# JLine only works from IDEA

Tags: java, jline

I have no problem using jline when the code is run within idea. Running with a bat file, the edit characters are not being sent to the terminal.

```
java -classpath ..\JActor\target\classes;..\JID\target\classes;target\classes;..\slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar;..\slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar;..\apache-sshd-0.8.0\lib\sshd-core-0.8.0.jar;..\apache-sshd-0.8.0\lib\mina-core-2.0.5.jar;..\apache-sshd-0.8.0\lib\bcprov-jdk15-140.jar;..\jline-2.9.jar;..\joda-time-2.1.jar org.agilewiki.jasocket.sshd.SSHServer %1%
```

I checked the jline jar file and it contains the fusesource code for jansi and hawtjni.

Comment: Is your terminal unicoded?

Comment: I'm using sshd to support remote access via PuTTY. I'm confused that running from IDEA would make a difference, though I get the sense that jline expect to be interacting with the local machine. So since I'm running from a windows command window, that might me an issue. Any way to force it?

Comment: make an environment suitable to do IO in that case

Comment: Added to my code:
        System.out.println(t.isAnsiSupported());
        System.out.println(t.isEchoEnabled());
        System.out.println(t.isSupported());
got true/false/true on dos window and false/false/true in idea.

environment? like, set a system property for the terminal type?

Comment: Copy/paste command from idea console to windows cmd prompt didn't work?

Comment: Yes, sysprop file.encoding

Comment: that copy/paste had no effect

Comment: then add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, or what encoding you have in IDEA?

Comment: I've tried jline.WindowsTerminal.ansi and
jline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole to no avail

Comment: using utf-8 in idea, setting that encoding when running java has no effect

Comment: check that `System.getProperty` in your code and compare.

Comment: are you running jline on the same machine?

Comment: how about user.language, and user.country?

Comment: yes! Only it looks like jline likes idea somehow. Now, I can force echo and local edits in putty and set the terminal type to none--that works. But that's not quite good enough for a product. :-/ And then I don't really need jline!

Comment: do you have the same value for both props, because this props could be used in character streams

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the Terminal used under IDEA and the dos box were different. Forcing the use of the IDEA terminal in all cases didn't work, but this did:

```
    consoleReader = new ConsoleReader(in, out, new TerminalSupport(true) {});
```

Comment: This same issue occurs when running from within Eclipse, and then later from within Tomcat.  The given fix works, although I still don't understand why even though I've been looking through the JLine2 code.